# adding custom SOAP header request

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, soap-client

Please I need help to add the following header to my SOAP request in C# ASP.net web application

```
    <wata:auth xmlns:wata="http://osb.wata.com">
       <username>username</username>
       <password>password</password>
    </wata:auth>
```

please note the tag should be the same  and already i tried to add this header by inheriting form Microsoft.Web.Service3.WebServicesClientProtocol but this will not work because the tag is different  .

The service call look like the following generated using WSDL definition

```
    service.ServiceProxy check = new service.ServiceProxy();
    check.checkPostService(serviceId);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add SOAP headers programmatically using the following :

```
service.ServiceProxy check = new service.ServiceProxy();

using (new OperationContextScope(check.InnerChannel))
{
      var usernameHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("username", string.Empty, _username);
      OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(usernameHeader);
      var passwordHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("password", string.Empty, _passowrd);
      OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(passwordHeader);

      check.checkPostService(serviceId);
}
```

Comment: can you explain more please where to add it .

Comment: I can't since you didn't share the code of your call to the web service. Please share it and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry but what about tag name should be <wata:auth>

Comment: Seconded ... how can you set the namespace of the headers, specifically to the ones used in WSSE:Security?